# How to pass data from route to component in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm using React Router to handle routing in my app, and I need to pass data from the route to the component being rendered. I'm not sure how to access the data in the component.

I have tried using the useEffect hook to store the data in local storage, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the data and update the state when the component mounts.

I expect to be able to persist data across components using React Hooks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the data as a prop of the component.

```
<Route path="<your_path>" element={<Component data ={value} />} />
```

or else you can use dynamic routes to pass the data in URL and then get the value using useParams() hook.

```
<Route path="<your_path>/:<dynamic_value>" element={<Component />} />
```

In component.js

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
function Component(){
const {<dynamic_value>} = useParams();
---rest of your logic---
}
```